# Using String Variables inside StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{} in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, streamingmarkupbuilder

for the Below code :

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
writer = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
Project(){MyTag('Help Me')}
}  
println(writer.toString()) 

the output would be: <Project><MyTag>Help Me</MyTag></Project>
```

Now if i have "MyTag('Help Me')" in above code as a string var and want to use as shown below

```
def teststring = "MyTag('Help Me')"
def writer = new StringWriter()
writer = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
Project(){out<<teststring}
}
println(writer.toString()) 

the output am getting is: MyTag('Help Me')<Project></Project>
but am expecting: <Project><MyTag>Help Me</MyTag></Project>
```

Am new to groovy,anybody help me with proper implementation or find the mistake for the above case ? Please let me know if I had to use other class other than StreamingMarkupBuilder and XmlMarkupBuilder ?
Note that in actual scenario for me the text variable actually contains a lot more of child nodes nested .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this;  Wrap the node string into a `{ -> }` and evaluate it as a Closure, then set the delegate and call the closure:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def nodes = '''MyTag( attr:'help me' ) {
              |    AnotherTag( 'Help me!' )
              |}'''.stripMargin()

println XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    Project {
        c = Eval.me( "{ -> $nodes }" )
        c.delegate = delegate
        c()
    }
} )
```

Which prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Project>
  <MyTag attr="help me">
    <AnotherTag>Help me!</AnotherTag>
  </MyTag>
</Project>
```

**However**, you must be careful, as if that `nodes` String comes from outside your system, it can be used to execute any code that is put in it.

If you're getting the nodes in a String, why not get them to write XML instead and save you a job? ;-)

Comment: Hey Tim thanks! both of your solution worked (second one being the suggestion) , but for the way i am generating the node text i felt first approach allowed me to write more readable code.

But i am still thinking if i have gone wrong in the implementation somewhere , logically getting nodes to write as XML should easy.